# Task List Percent Complete Column not populating correctly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, task-list

I have a task list where one of the columns is the " % Complete ", which I'm trying to populate based on where the progress is made in an accompanying workflow.  However, the column keeps populating to either "0" or "1000 (for 10%, for example)".  I've tried multiple variations, but still come up with the same results.  Is there something I'm missing for this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate the "%Complete" column, Please refer to the below screenshot:

[image]

Log to variable value:

[image]

Updated column:

[image: ![enter image description here]